# Can i crypt function calls and events declarations in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello i want to know if it is possible to encrypt functions calls and events declarations in VB.NET or even reserved words in VB.NET ?

Comment: Why in the world would anybody want to encrypt calls and declarations?

Comment: i want to secure it manually with out external tools

Answer (score 0):

Look for a vb.net obfuscater...

[Here is link](http://igservice.zapto.org)

Comment: @user3348284 you can try giving your subs and methods random names but that isnt the most secure way... Other than that (unless you edit the whole .net framework, which wont work), you have no other option. (or u can obfuscate it...)